# Trying to add 2 Counter dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, counter

Trying to add 2 Python dictionaries in Python 3.

For example:

```
dict1 = {'a': 10,'b':20}
dict2 =  {'a': 30,'b':30}
```

expected result:

```
dict_sum = {'a': 40,'b':50}
```

Code:

```
A = Counter (dict1)
B = Counter(dict2)
dict_sum = A + B
```

Result:

```
Counter() #empty counter object
```

Still getting an empty counter object.

I checked on the type of keys and values in `A` and `B` with result as follows:

```
<class 'dict_values'>
<class 'dict_keys'>
```

Please suggest to me where am I going wrong.

Comment: Can not reproduce.  If `A` were really a counter, then those types would be like `<function Counter.keys>` not `<class 'dict_keys'>`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could you check your code once again? Here is my code:

```
from collections import Counter


dict1 = {'a': 10,'b': 20}
dict2 = {'a': 30,'b': 30}

new_counter = Counter(dict1) + Counter(dict2)
print(new_counter)

# Counter({'b': 50, 'a': 40})
```

To @vikky: Check your environment first. This code works well. If it's not working, you might need to check your environment first.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jun 29 2016, 14:05:02) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> dict1 = {'a': 10, 'b': 20}
>>> dict2 = {'a': 30, 'b': 30}
>>> Counter(dict1) + Counter(dict2)
Counter({'b': 50, 'a': 40})
```

It works on Python 3 as well.

```
$ python
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> dict1 = {'a': 10, 'b': 20}
>>> dict2 = {'a': 30, 'b': 30}
>>> Counter(dict1) + Counter(dict2)
Counter({'b': 50, 'a': 40})
```

Comment: @vikky Interesting. I think it's not related to your source code. If you use some IDE or jupyter notebook or something else, please open new one and try it again.